# Finding the equation of the line tangent to $x^2+y^2-6x+4y-3=0$ passing through $(7,4)$. How to proceed, not knowing point of tangency?

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

> Find the equation of the tangent line to the circle $x^2+y^2-6x+4y-3=0$ which passes through the point $(7,4)$.

Graphing the circle, $(7,4)$ is a point not on the circle. So, I am assuming it's on the tangent line.

> How do you find the equation of the tangent line? Explanation needed.

Comment: Look through the related questions at right. There are at least two problems similar to your there.

Comment: Hint: method 1: find chord of contact by substituting $xx_1+yy_1+1/2(x+x_1)+1/2(y+y_1)+c=0$ and assume the points h, k find the equation off the tangent by two point form and solve the two equations simultaneously you will get your answer. Method 2: get the centre of the circle g, h find the normal passing through the circle centre and then solve it and proceed as an method 1 you get your answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

$$(x-3)^2+(y+2)^2=4^2$$

If $\dfrac{y-4}{x-7}=m\iff mx-y+4-7m=0$ be the tangent of the circle, the perpendicular distance of the line from the center $(3,2)$ will be $=4$(radius)

$$4=\left|\dfrac{3m-(-2)+4-7m}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}\right|$$

$$\iff16(m^2+1)=(2-4m)^2\iff m=\infty,?$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The desired tangent line $L$ must pass through some point $(x,y)$ on the circle, satisfying its equation, as well as through the point $(7,4)$. The last condition implies the equation of $L$ is $$y = m(x-7)+4.$$

Implicitly differentiating the equation of the circle to find the relevant tangent line's slope yields
$$
2x + 2yy' - 6 + 4y' = 0 \implies y' = \frac{6-2x}{2y+4}
 = \frac{3-x}{y+2}
$$

So $L$ passes through some $(x^*,y^*)$ satisfying the equation of the curve, and the equation of the line itself must be
$$
y = \frac{3-x^*}{y^*+2}(x-7)+4,
$$
and the point $(x^*,y^*)$ must satisfy this as well...

Answer (score 1):

Without calculus, refer to the graph:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

To find the line $AB$, let $B(x,y)$, then:
$$\begin{cases}AB=AC=6 \\ OB=4\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} (7-x)^2+(4-y)^2=6^2 \\ (3-x)^2+(-2-y)^2=4^2 \end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
(x,y)=C(7,-2); B\left(\frac{19}{13}, \frac{22}{13}\right)$$

Hence, the tangent line $AC$ is $x=7$ and the tangent line $AB$ is $y=\frac5{12}x+\frac{13}{12}.$